# Apache can not work, when updated to php5.5

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I install **apache**, **php5.3**, **passenger** with apache on my ubuntu server.

I try to follow this [link](http://phpave.com/upgrade-php-5-3-php-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts/#.UzKYFK2Sy8Q) to upgrade php5.3 to php5.5.

I type `$ php -v`, it show me the correct version.

But When I try to stop and start apache, It alert me:

```
$ service apache2 stop
 * Stopping web server apache2                                                                                                                                                   *

$ service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                   *
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.24/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.24/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I think maybe passenger cause. but how to fix it?

Comment: Try Stopping your **apache** and then start your apache server. Because restart may not give you enough solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
sudo etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

Try these commands as well after start command

```
service apache2 stop
```

Than restart server

Comment: Not work,i think command ```service restart``` equals ```service stop; service start```

Comment: which Operating u r using ?